# How can I separate list values on the basis of type - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

From a list containing ints, strings, and floats, make three lists to store them separately.

Please help how can I separate list values on the basis of type.

Comment: Where is the problem with your code?

Comment: Refer [How to create minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> lst = [1, 'a', 2.0, 2]
>>> for v in lst:
...     d[type(v).__name__].append(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'int': [1, 2], 'str': ['a'], 'float': [2.0]})
`

Comment: Have a look at the ``isinstance`` builtin function.

Comment: Hi All,

Thanks for your suggestions and response.

This is my first post so I don't know more about it, next time I improve my questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use type.

```
test = [3, "hello", 2.4]

int_array = []
string_array = []
float_array = []

for value in test:
    check = type(value)
    if check == int:
        int_array.append(value)
    elif check == str:
        string_array.append(value)
    elif check == float:
        float_array.append(value)
```